# How to compare YEAR types in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, join

I've searched and searched to no avail for what seems like an incredible stupid question.  I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.team_name, s.stad_name s.built
FROM teams t INNER JOIN
     stadiums s
     ON s.stad_id = t.team_stad
WHERE s.built < 1950
```

and I keep getting errors left and right.  I've tried putting 1950 in single quotes, double quotes, and everything else.  Built is a YEAR(4) data type.

So, how do you compare YEAR data types in mysql?

EDIT: I knew I was staring at this too long, and too late.  A comma........thank you for your answers, and kindness.

Comment: What problem do you have?  Your methods should be working.

Comment: Put `comma` between `s.stad_name` and `s.built` columns and then try it will work. You forgot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put **comma (,)** between `s.stad_name` and `s.built` columns and then try it will work. You forgot it

Try this:

```
SELECT t.team_name, s.stad_name, s.built 
FROM teams t 
INNER JOIN stadiums s ON s.stad_id = t.team_stad 
WHERE s.built < 1950;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT t.team_name, s.stad_name, s.built  //You Missed Comma...
 FROM teams t INNER JOIN
 stadiums s
 ON s.stad_id = t.team_stad
 WHERE s.built < 1950
```